# nodejs: Access variables in routes

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, restify

Here is how my `routes.js` looks like:

```
module.exports = function (server, db) {

    // Deals
    const deals = require('./controllers/deals');
    server.get('/deals', deals.findAll);
    server.get('/deals/:id', deals.findById);
    server.post('/deals', deals.add);
    server.put('/deals/:id', deals.update);
    server.del('/deals/:id', deals.delete);

}
```

As you can see, there are `server` and `db` variables here. However, I'm not sure how could I pass these two variables to `deals.findAll`, and other REST methods.

Here is how `deals.findAll` method looks:

```
const findAll = (req, res, next) => {
   // I need to access db here, so I can use Sequelize.
}

exports.findAll = findAll
```

The reason I need db is Sequelize ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to do this:

```
module.exports = function (server, db) {

    // Deals
    const deals = require('./controllers/deals');
    server.get('/deals', deals.findAll.bind(null, server, db));
    server.get('/deals/:id', deals.findById.bind(null, server, db));
    server.post('/deals', deals.add.bind(null, server, db));
    server.put('/deals/:id', deals.update.bind(null, server, db));
    server.del('/deals/:id', deals.delete.bind(null, server, db));
}
```

The `Function.prototype.bind()` method *prepends* those arguments, so you need to modify the parameters of those functions to:

```
const findAll = (server, db, req, res, next) => {
   // server & db is set here
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks.